# "queueproxy" : error reverse proxying request; sockstat: sockets TCP: inuse 27 orphan 2 tw 20 alloc 593 mem 52

Tags: istio, istio-gateway, knative, knative-eventing

I've issue with respect to above subject, using
knative v1.2.5
istio 1.12.7

Every 20mins we see below error in the queue proxy,

error: "context canceled"
knative.dev/key: "test-common-service/test-app-0-0-0"
knative.dev/pod: "test-app-0-0-0-deployment-xxxxxxx-xxxxx"
logger: "queueproxy"
message: "error reverse proxying request; sockstat: sockets: used 44
TCP: inuse 27 orphan 2 tw 20 alloc 593 mem 52
UDP: inuse 0 mem 3
UDPLITE: inuse 0
RAW: inuse 0
FRAG: inuse 0 memory 0

Can someone please let me know how can I fix this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may have requests which are hitting request timeouts in the queue proxy. What is your typical request latency, and what is the Revision `timeoutSeconds` set to?

It's also possible that istio is cancelling (resetting) some of the TCP connections to the queue-proxy, but that seems unlikely.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for taking time and replying, revision-timeout-seconds: "300"  # 5 minutes and we are  getting that error after 20mins....

It will run for 20mins and throw that error the it will start running for another 20mins and the samething.

Thanks